# Calling user profile image and resize it

Tags: php, html, twitter

I've got the following code which shows twitter user data in my system. My issue is with the profile picture, it's retrieved it from my db which I use it in another place with small size. I can't figure out how to adjust the field to take profile img from twitter itself and resize it in 200x200 px

```
<div class="profile">
        <center><a href="http://www.twitter.com/<?=$fields[1]?>" class="text_bigger2"><?=$fields[2]?></a><br />@<a href="http://www.twitter.com/<?=$fields[1]?>"><?=$fields[1]?></a><br /><br /><a href="http://www.twitter.com/<?=$fields[1]?>" > <img height=110 src="<?=$fields[7]?>" /> </a></center>
        <br/>
        <center><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="I'm ranked # <?=$fields[0]?> in Sudanesetweeps.com" data-via="SudaneseTweeps">Tweet</a></center>
        </br>
        <ul>
            <li>I'm ranked # <span class="color"><?=$fields[0]?></span> in Sudanesetweeps.com</li>
            <li><span class="color"><?=$fields[3]?></span> <?=$followers_diff?> Followers</li>
            <li><span class="color"><?=$fields[4]?></span> <?=$tweets_diff?> Tweets</li>
            <li><?=$fields[5]?></li>
        </ul>    
</div>
```

Live demo is here  http://www.sudanesetweeps.com/new/find.php?username=altayeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the size for an image.

bigger - 73px by 73px
normal - 48px by 48px
mini - 24px by 24px
original - undefined. This will be the size the image was originally uploaded in. The filesize of original images can be very big so use this parameter with caution.
Example Values: bigger

Example Requests

GET http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/twitterapi.json

GET http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=mobinga&size=bigger

^^ You should use the second example to get the image in the big format. Rename the screen name to your preferred choice.

[API Doc](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/%3ascreen_name)

Answer (score 0):

use this site : http://tweetimag.es/   this will help you get any twitter profile picture with the sizes available.